# The current situation of the Godbillon-Vey invariant conjecture

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, foliations

Suppose we have a compact three-manifold $M$, a codimension-one foliation $F$ of $M$, and a one-form on $\alpha$, chosen so that $F$ is tangent to $\alpha = 0$. We deduce that $\alpha \wedge d\alpha = 0$.  Also, there is some one-form $\beta$ so that $d\alpha = \alpha \wedge \beta$.

The *Godbillon-Vey invariant* of $F$ is defined as the cohomology class of $\beta \wedge d\beta$. This class is independent of the choices made (at least up to sign).

Then we have the following  question which is raised by  Etienne Ghys:

**Conjecture:** The Godbillon-Vey invariant is a topological invariant.

See the  paper  É. Ghys, L’invariant de Godbillon–Vey, Astérisque (1989) 177–178, Exp. No. 706, Séminaire
Bourbaki, Vol. 1988/89, 155–181

That is, two topologically equivalent foliations have the same Godbillon-Vey class.

> What are some updates on this conjecture?

Comment: Are there examples of smooth foliations on a 3-manifold M that are topologically equivalent but not diffeomorphic?

Comment: I was thinking of M compact, and I assume this question is, too.

Comment: @DanielAsimov  Dear Prof. Asimov, Thank you  for your attention to my question and  your  edit. I  think a smooth invariant of  a Reeb foliation of $S^3$ is the derivative of Holonomy map defined on a  1 dimensional transversal. So If we introduce two different Reeb foliations $F_1, F_2 $ with different $p_1'(0), p_2'(0)$, the  derivative of Poincare or Holonomy map  so they are  not  smooth  equivalent.

Comment: @DanielAsimov  On the  other hand  I am thinking to some other possible counter example: First We know  that there are examples which show that Hartman Grobman is  valid topologicaly but not in C^1 class(Around singularity). So I wonder can we introduce  a  vector field around singularity at $0\in \mathbb{R}^4$  which is topologically linearaizable but not smoothly. Then after a  Blow  up of  singularity  can we obtain two 0n1 dimensional foliation of $S^3$ which are topological equivalent but not smooth equivalent?

Comment: As anotnter her possible  counter example I would like to pose the following question:

Comment: Two  Kronecker  foliations of  tori  with slops $\alpha, \beta$ are not topological equiivalent if $\alpha , \beta$ do not lie on the same orbits of the  action of  $SL(2,\mathbb{R}$ via action $\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}.z=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$. Now Consider the product foliations by $F_1\times S^1$ and $F_2\times S^1$. In this way, can we obtain two topological equivalent foliation of $\mathbb{T}^3$ which  are not smoothly equivalent?

Comment: I  would  appreciate if  you let me  know  a precise counter example  of two  topological 
 equivalent but non smooth equivalent foliations if there exist any.

Comment: @SamNead  Thank  you  for  your edit

Comment: @Ali Taghavi - regarding your requested counterexample (immediately above): do you require both foliations be smooth?  There are "easy" examples where one foliation is smooth and the other is not.  See Figure 2 and Section 3 of *Osculating curves: around the Tait-Kneser Theorem* by Ghys, Tabachnikov, and Timorin.

Comment: Ali Taghavi: Re the comment mentioning the action of SL(2,ℝ): That should be SL(2,ℤ) instead.

Comment: @DanielAsimov yes  Thank you I was mistaken. It is  inded $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$

Comment: @DanielAsimov  Sorry for my mistake

Comment: I also do not understand "Holonomy map defined on a 1 dimensional transversal". Don't you need a closed curve along a leaf to get a holonomy map?

Comment: Never mind, I see what you mean by a 1-dimensional transversal.

Comment: I now see that it is easy to find two topologically equivalent, oriented smooth foliations on the 2-torus that are not smoothly equivalent: Omitting details: Consider two (1,0) unit vector fields V_1, V_2 — each with two closed orbits — with V_1, V_2 having holonomy maps with distinct derivatives. Then multiplying the torus and each leaf by S^1 gives such examples of smooth codimension-1 foliations on the 3-torus.

Comment: @DanielAsimov  yes this gives topological equivalent non smooth equivalent foliation. Thank you.

Comment: @DanielAsimov  I think I was mistaken, Sorry.  Because  an  smooth equivalent need not preserve the  derivative of  Poincare return map. My mistake initiated from the following confusion:  Two smooth equivalent singularity have  conjugate(similar) linear part. So  do you agree my argument and  hence  your argumenyt do not work?

Comment: @DanielAsimov  May be there is a  counterexample in the  Novikov  book  or  Toender book?  Thank you for your  chalenging question. (Existence of two foliation topological equivalent but not smooth equivalent)

Comment: @DanielAsimov BTW i think that there are some works on Godbilon Vey invariant of Lie Groups by Robert Roussarie

Comment: @SamNead thank you for the reference by Ghys. I think Daniel Asimov meant two smooth foliation which are not smooth equivalent but are topological equivalent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out:

*Hilsum, Michel*, [**Functions with bounded variation and the class of Godbillon-Vey**](https://doi.org/10.1093/qmath/hav013), Q. J. Math. 66, No. 2, 547-562 (2015). [ZBL1401.57040](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1401.57040).

Comment: Thank you very much for your very helpful answer and very intetesting paper a partial solutions to a problem raised by E. Ghys

Comment: @AliTaghavi maybe you could update your question with a reference to Ghys’ paper where the question was posed

Comment: yes that is a good idea. I will update it  ASAP

Comment: I  did updated the  question. Thank  you  for  your suggestion